# How to space onclick in android studio

Tags: android, keyboard, onclicklistener

On OnKeyboardActionListener methods,How to write a method for getting space when a button is clicked in Android studio .I got for delete button and could'nt find out for space ?

```
Button delete = (Button) keyboardLayout.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button space = (Button) keyboardLayout.findViewById(R.id.space);
    space.setOnClickListener(this);

case R.id.delete:

            inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(2, 0);

            break;

        case R.id.space:


            break;
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. Consider finding a proper tutorial and writing some simple applications.

Comment: @iehrlich I edited my question .That might help you to answer my question !